# How to find server name of SQL server

Tags: sql-server, server

[I want to connect with Windows authentication mode, but i havent find my server name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d21jm.png) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d21jm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute this query:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

Or else you can find it from the SQL Server COnfiguration manager:

[image]

From [here](http://sqlserver-help.com/2011/06/19/help-whats-my-sql-server-name/):

> - Open SQL Server Configuration Manager (SSCM) from Start – > All    Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2005/2008/2008 R2 -> Configuration
>     Tools.
>
>   - In the SSCM, click SQL Server Services under SQL Server Configuration    Manager (Local), you could find list like SQL Server
>       (InstanceName),
>   - The InstanceName is what we need to find, instance name. If you    install multiple instances on the server, you will see more than one
>       SQL Server (InstanceName) listed.

Comment: Doesn't he need to be connected to the server to run this query?

Comment: @Lamak:- Updated my answer!

Comment: Yeah, I undownvoted, but op seemed aware of this option already (looking at the image posted in the question)

Answer (score 0):

if SQL SERVER is installed on your machine then it is either
1. 127.0.0.1
2. localhost
3. .
4. ./SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Go to  CONFIGURATION tools. They are installed as part of the MICROSOFT SQL SERVER package. I dont remember the exact name of the option. Go through all the options, one of them should have the name of the server.